# Prevent an element from covering another

Tags: html, css, z-index, positioning

I have a fixed header. As I scroll, certain elements cover the header. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the z-index for the divs:

```
#headercontainer {
    z-index:1;
}
#contentcontainer {
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Adding the above lines should give your header priority over the content container.

Comment: As per my answer, only one of them needs the z-index set.

Comment: Very true, I just have a habbit of setting something I know I want to stay at the very bottom a z-index of -1 :)

Comment: I added a z-index of -1 and it made my chat box disappear so I set it to 0 instead and it's now visible but doesn't override my other element/icon when clicked. So this answer helped, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions I can think of quickly off the top of my head. You can either give the `#headercontainer` element a [z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp)...

```
#headercontainer {
    /* ... other CSS ... */
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

... or you can do it the way I think it should be done...

```
#headercontainer {
    /* ... other CSS ... */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#contentcontainer {
    /* ... other CSS ... */
    margin-top: 125px; /* this should be at least the height of the header */
}
```

In the second solution, you don't have to worry about which element is hovering over which other element. The `#contentcontainer` element is properly pushed down under the `#headercontainer` element so that they have no overlap.

Comment: +1, this is definitely the better solution. I'd initially tried this, but I was missing `header {top: 0}` so it didn't actually work.

Comment: Thanks for the options and your opinion mate, I'm not really familiar with z-index so I'd probably go for the second option too

Comment: @Jake... by the way, Stack Overflow tradition shows that the most helpful answer is usually marked as "Accepted". So whichever of these (currently) 3 answers is most helpful, you should accept.

Comment: I ended up using the z-index by the way. Without it, when I scroll, the contentcontainer div goes back over the headercontainer. Just thought I'd let you know

Comment: That is because you're using the `position: fixed` property. That will keep the header at the top of the page always, no matter what, even when you scroll.

Comment: @Jake you can use `position: absolute` instead of `fixed` to solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Give the `#headercontainer` a higher z-index:

```
#headercontainer {
    z-index: 10;
}
```